# Libgdx: The import org.json cannot be resolved

Tags: libgdx

The following error occurs when I try to compile my project to Html with `gradlew html:superDev` command. In Android and Desktop is Ok.

```
[ERROR] Line 14: The import org.json cannot be resolved
  [ERROR] Line 51: JSONObject cannot be resolved to a type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need sources for every library you use for GWT to compile it to JS.

As a general advice, if you use features libGDX provides itself, you should not use third libs to avoid such problems. Use the built-in json parser.

Comment: This means I have to use JsonReader ?